# Using sed to replace a pattern like given below

Tags: regex, sed

I have to change function declaration, so, I need to change all the calling instances.

Existing One: `my_func( a, b, c, ***d, e***, f, g);`
New One: `my_func( a, b, c, **XYZ**, f, g);`

Means need to change d, e to XYZ. Here, d and e can represent anything and XYZ is fixed string. So, I need to replace string between 3rd comma and 5th comma with XYZ.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after lots of trial I found my answer. Below is the command that worked for me.

```
echo "my_func( a, b, c, d, e, f, g);" | sed 's/\(my_func(\)\(\([^,]*,\)\{3\}\)\([^,]*,[^,]*\)/\1\2 XYZ/g'
```

Actually, I was working with an instance having pattern with multiple lines.

For multiple line:

```
my_func( a, b, c, 
         d, e, f, g); 

sed 'N; s/\(my_func(\)\(\([^,]*,\)\{3\}\)\([^,]*,[^,]*\)/\1\2 XYZ/g' file_name > output_file
```

Comment: if you are using GNU sed, you can shorten it to `sed -r 's/(my_func\()(([^,]+,){3})(([^,]+,){2})/\1\2 XYZ,/'`

Comment: Thanks @sp-asic , I am using GNU sed. Do you know how to apply regexp in sed  for both multi line and one line matched string. With "N", it is not working with one line matched string and without "N", multi line matched string is not working. Thanks in advance!!